# How Frequency Division Multiplexing is Shared?

Tags: signals, communication

I understand that frequency division multiplexing is splitting the frequency spectrum into a frequency band then sending that through the medium. However what I dont understand is how its received.

```
Does the user who received the signal have access to all the frequencies on the band or
only a specific channel?
```

I ask because I saw the with Time division multiplexing each user has access to the entire band for a short time burst, and the content i'm reading shy's away from this area.

Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague and too general. Could you make it more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example: Broadcast television is a form of frequency division multiplexing. Each channel is broadcast on a different frequency and the signals for all stations are received by a TV antenna are present at the input of the TV tuber. The TV tuner is basically a filter that extracts the signal from a specified frequency band.

Whether the user is considered to have full access depends on what equipment is sitting between the user and the transmission channel. E.g. communications between telephone exchanges usually uses TDM, but on the telephone line from the exchange to my house I only get the signal intended for me.

Comment: Thanks for that! Simple, clear and excellent analogy, I was stuck on the understanding of that for far to long! :D